# Open ng-bootstrap modal programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap, ng-template

I've got an angular 4 page including a ng-bootstrap modal. My code looks like this.

foo.html

```
[...]
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary material-icons"
(click)="open(content)">search</button>

<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    content in here
</ng-template>
[...]
```

foo.ts

```
[...]
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
[...]
open(content) {
   let options: NgbModalOptions = {
     size: 'lg'
   };

   this.modalService.open(content, options);
}
[...]
```

Now when I click the button the modal opens. What I want to do now is open the model on ngChanges.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
   open(content)
}
```

My problem is: How do I get the "content" here? Is there any way to get the ng-template programmatically? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To access the `content` element inside the class, declare:

```
@ViewChild('content', { static: false }) private content;
                         ^for Angular8+
```

and add the corresponding import at the top of the class:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

and finally call open method for that element on change detection:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
   this.open(this.content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

from Angular 8 you should also pass static option: `{static: false}` in ViewChild

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('content', { static: false }) private content;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

this.modalService.open(this.content);
```