# how to open ng-template modal from component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a modal wrapped in ng-template,

```js
<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal for user id : {{ modalService.config.initialState.id }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

i have a button to open this modal like

```js
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    const user = {
        id: 10
      };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {
      initialState : user
    });
}
```

this will work as i am passing template as a parameter.

How can i open this modal without passing the parameter? let it be i dont have a button, i want to open the modal on ngOninit. How it is possible?

[stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstap-gqmajr)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open ng-bootstrap modal programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133209/open-ng-bootstrap-modal-programmatically)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the reference of the template in typescript using `@ViewChild()` decorator and use `ngAfterViewInit()` hook to open the modal..

```js
@ViewChild('template') templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const user = {
      id: 10
    };
  this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.templateRef, {
    initialState : user
  });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstap-pay2ua?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**Edit**

I just noticed that we would be getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` if we show it in `ngAfterViewInit()` hook, to fix that wrap opening the modal in a `setTimeuut()`

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.templateRef, {
      initialState : user
   })
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstap-pr377t?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple method to open `<ng-template> </ng-template>` modal in angular.

You can use modalService to open the modal, add below in .ts-file .

step 1: `import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

step 2:  `constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)`

step 3:

```
function openModal(template) {
             this.modalService.open(template);
         }
```

When the button will be pressed, the function `openModal()` will be
triggered and the 'template' parameter will pass as an argument. This
in turn will trigger the modalService and open the modal 'template'.

Comment: "When the button will be pressed, " - this is not the question being asked. The user want to know how to open the modal programmiclly.

Comment: The user already has mentioned "i have a button to open this modal like" , so the button click is the event to open the modal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator to get the reference and to load initially use [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) hook which called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view.

```
import { Component,TemplateRef, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const user = {
        id: 10
      };
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.template, {
      initialState : user
    });
  }

}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstap-pz6swt)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular is simple way of ng-template modal from component

like bellow

import NgbModal :

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
  private modalService: NgbModal
 ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.openModal('template');
 }

openModal(template) {
 this.modalService.open(template);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
```

ts

```
 @ViewChild('content') content: any;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.open()
   })
}


  open(){
            this.modalService.open(this.content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then(
            (result) => {
                this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
            },
            (reason) => {
                this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
            },
        );
  }
```