# How to open ng-bootstrap modal popup on pageload in angular 7?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap, modalpopup

I am unable to display the ng-bootstrap modal popup on page load in angular 7.

i have tried the below code to open it.

```
openVerticallyCentered(content) {

this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });.
this.modalService.open(content, { beforeDismiss: false });

}
```

Comment: See this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55449627/4976422

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use ViewChild decorator to reach content on init.

Demo here.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd8tny?embed=1&file=app/modal-basic.ts